# Access http session when using two different Java Web frameworks

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs, zk

I'm currently developing a 'toy' project using java web and MVC pattern.

I'm currently using Hibernate for DAOs and ZK for the user interface while using a number of controller classes to implement the application logic.

Now I want to add another View, a RESTful interface using JAX-RS and I0ve noticed I'm using a framework-provided class to get the http context. ZK provides the session class:

```
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Sessions;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session;
[...]
Session s = Sessions.getCurrent();
s.setAttribute("some_attr", some_object);
```

Meanwhile JAX-RS (Apache wink) provides the Context annotation with whom you can annotate a HttpServletRequest attribute:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; ///< Interface
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; ///< Interface
[...]
@Context
HttpServletRequest context;
[...]
HttpSession s = context.getSession();
s.setAttribute("some_attr", some_object);
```

*How can I get the current context without using either ZK or JAX-RS so I can make the controller layer independent of the view used?*

Answer (score 0):

`javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` is part of the Servlet API, not JAX-RS. So it is the most fundamental API to use HTTP Sessions and as I understand ZK it uses the Servlet API under the hood. The @Context annotation is fron Java EE and also standard.

Use the second form, they are stable and independent!

If you do not have any other framework (like spring, ...) you may write a servlet filter copying the session to a `ThreadLocal` and retrieve that in your code instead of injecting it.

Comment: I'm currently using Tomcat 7 and it seems like the @Context annotation is only provided by jax-rs. Is there any way to replicate the annotation behavior without changing container?